# How does kommutation affect unification in first oder predicate logic

Tags: logic, unification

This was asked on an exam last semester. I know that my algorithm fails in this case, or does it not? because of the function being not the same like $g(f(x))=f(g(x))$.

The problem: given by  2 lists $(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ and $(t_1,\dots,t_n)$
can be seen as solving a system of equations
$$\Gamma=[s_1=t_1,\dots ,s_n=t_n]$$

This can be done by the following rules that were similarly formulated by J. Herbrand in 1930.

- $x, y, z_i$ are variables
- $a,b$ constance
- $p_i,q_i,s$ and $s_i$ are arbitrary terms.
- $t$ is a term and not a variable

1. remove every equation $s=s$ in $\Gamma$
2. replace every equation $f(p_1,\dots,p_n)=f(q_1,\dots, q_n)$ with $p_1=q_1\dots,p_n=q_n$
3. for every equation $x=s$, for which $x$ is not under the variables of Term $s$, substitute every other occurrence of $x$ in $\Gamma$ with $s$.
4. replace every eqation $t=x$ with $x=t$.
5. if there is an equation like $a=b$ in $\Gamma$, there is no solution.
6. if there is an equation like $f(p_1,\dots,p_n)=g(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ in $\Gamma$, there is no solution.
7. if there is an equation like $f(p_1,\dots,p_n)=a$ or $a=f(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ in $\Gamma$, there is no solution.
8. if there is an equation like $x=t$ in $\Gamma$ where $x$ occurs in $t$ there is no solution

The system is solved when it only consists of $z_i=s_i (i=1,...,k)$
where $z_i$ doesn't occur else in $\Gamma$. Then the unificator of the 2 lists ist the substitution $\{z_1\leftarrow s_1,\dots,z_k\leftarrow s_k\}$

Comment: You need to provide more detail about your definitions and what you've tried.

Comment: Added the algorithm in question

Comment: It surely affects rule 6. But I don't clearly understand the problem. Are the commutative functions given in some way?

Comment: yes, its given that $g(f(x))$ is semantically the same as $f(g(x))$

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. What are you asking?